# Calling a method inside fragment class using the Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to add a fragment to my activity and call a method which is inside the fragment class from the activity. 
I tested the fragment without calling the method from the activity class and the fragment gets displayed in the activity without any problems. However i am unable to call the method inside the fragment class.

Below is my code in the activity class.

Using the below method i call the fragment to be displayed in my activity when a button is clicked.

```
public void checkTimes(View view){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    table_fragment tablefragment = new table_fragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, tablefragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Below is the code of the fragment class and populate data method is the method i want to call.

```
public class table_fragment extends Fragment {

View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

/**
 * Method used to populate dates in the fragment
 * @param startDate
 * @param endDate
 */
public void populateData(Context context,LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate){
    ArrayList<LocalDate> dates = Utility.calculateDates(startDate,endDate);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTable);  //getting the table layout in the fragment
    for(LocalDate date : dates){
        TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(context);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TextView tv=new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(date.toString());
        tableRow.addView(tv);

        table.addView(tableRow);
    }
}
}
```

I want to call the populate date method from the activity class and display the fragment.

How can i achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make one method like below and then using tablefragment call your method.
and call this method from activity.
and add your fragment using xml file.

```
  public void setDataAccordingToYourNeed(){
       table_fragment tablefragment=getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(your_fragment_id);
       tablefragment.yourFragmentMethod();
    }
```

this will surely solve your problem,if you didnt get let me know